# Set parameter default from SQL query in Birt

Tags: birt

Is there a way how to set parameter default value from SQL query?I have a report which takes parameters with id, fromDate and toDate. And I would like to have fromDate parameter default value obtained from database (it should be date of creation of the object with id from the first parameter). So any hints how to do this?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic report parameter that retrieves the date from a data set.  Then link your new data set parameter to the report parameter.

Comment: your solution works if user has to do a listbox. I have to display that value in a textbox and dynamic checkbox is disabled.